# How to use ~/.bashrc aliases on IPython 3.2.0?

Tags: bash, ipython, alias, jupyter-notebook

I need to use my aliases from `~/.bashrc` on IPython.

First I've tried but it didn't work

```
%%bash 
source ~/.bashrc
```

According to [this post](https://twitter.com/fperez_org/status/352181845980479488) we should do

```
%%bash 
. ~/.bashrc
f2py3 -v
```

It takes 20 sec to run on Jupiter and I get:

> bash: line 2: f2py3: command not found

My `~/.bashrc` file looks like

```
alias f2py3='$HOME/python/bin/f2py'
```

> bash: line 2: type: f2py3: not found

Neither alias, source, nor %rehashx% work

```
%%bash
alias f2py3='$HOME/python/bin/f2py'
```

I actually found that the problem is Python, who can't execute `alias` command neither with sh nor bash.

Can I use alias with IPython magics?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your bashrc file in the ipython config and add any custom aliases you have defined:

```
import re
import os.path

c = get_config()

with open(os.path.expanduser('~/.bashrc')) as bashrc:
    aliases = []
    for line in bashrc:
        if line.startswith('alias'):
            parts = re.match(r"""^alias (\w+)=(['"]?)(.+)\2$""", line.strip())
            if parts:
                source, _, target = parts.groups()
                aliases.append((source, target))

    c.AliasManager.user_aliases = aliases
```

This should be placed in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`.

`%rehashx` makes system commands available in the alias table so is also very useful if you want to use ipython as a shell.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. I've added `echo 'reading .bashrc'` to my ~/.bashrc but I don't see anything after doing %rehashx%. I don't have `alias ll='ls -l'` but I still get the same as you get

Comment: @ilciavo You are right, I have changed my answer accordingly. `%rehashx` may still be useful to you, but this seems to be a reasonable way to make your aliases available.